# PrimeNG Table filterGlobal TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular, primeng

All of the examples I have found for the PrimeNG `p-table` show the following example for filtering a table.

`<input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Filter" />`

When I use this I get a compile error.

`error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

Note: I do have strict mode turned on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to parse the target to an HTMLInputElement first:

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="applyFilterGlobal($event, 'contains')" placeholder="Filter" />
```

and in your component:

```
applyFilterGlobal($event, stringVal) {
  this.dt.filterGlobal(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, stringVal);
}
```

event.target is an HTMLElement, because you are in strict mode, and HTMLElement doesnt have the value property, the compile engine throws the error, changing the target to HTMLInputElement solves it

Comment: I had left off a few other parts, Lazy loading etc...   It works now.  Not compiling was stopping me from getting to the other parts.  Thank You!

Comment: Might be better to pass `stringVal` through to `filterGlobal()` so that the operator is defined in the page and passed through.

Answer (score 17):

Your HTML input should be like this

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="applyFilterGlobal($event, 'contains')" placeholder="Filter" />
```

and in your TS do this

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table'
...
applyFilterGlobal($event: any, stringVal: any) {
    this.dt!.filterGlobal(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, stringVal);
  }
```

if you get error for dt add below line

```
  @ViewChild('dt') dt: Table | undefined;
```

Comment: Following above answer with small change worked for me -             
  applyFilterGlobal($event: any, stringVal: any) {
    this.dt?.filterGlobal(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, 'contains');
  }

Comment: ```import { Table } from 'primeng/table';```

Answer (score 8):

```
<input pInputText #textInput type="text(input)="tt.filterGlobal(textInput.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Filter" />
```

Adding `#textInput` to the tag worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Instead following code,

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Global Search" />`
```

Try following. This worked for me.

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value, 'contains')" placeholder="Global Search" />`
```

I added "$any"for $event.target.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use an [Angular Template Reference](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) in the input tag.

`<input pInputText #textInput type="text(input)="dt.filterGlobal(textInput.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Filter" />`

`#textInput` above is a reference to an input tag so it has a value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

1. write a function in component to retrieve the value of $event by passing the $event

```
getEventValue($event:any) :string {
  return $event.target.value;
}
```

2. apply the above function in your HTML code.

```
 <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt1.filterGlobal(getEventValue($event), 'contains')" placeholder="Search keyword" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Globally tell Angular not to check the type of DOM event bindings by disabling `strictDomEventTypes`:

```json
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true
    "strictDomEventTypes": false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the previous answers, this worked for me:

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="applyFilterGlobal($event, 'contains', table)" placeholder="Search keyword" />
```

where table is your #table reference in the table like `<p-table #table ...>`. Then:

```
applyFilterGlobal($event: any, stringVal: any, dt: any) {
   dt!.filterGlobal(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, 'contains');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

parse the target by using $any() on template. like,

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value, 'contains')" placeholder="Filter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML Use This.

```
<input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt1.filterGlobal(applyFilterGlobal($event), 'contains')" placeholder="Search keyword" />
```

In TS file use:

```
  applyFilterGlobal(event: any) {
    return event.target.value;
  }
```